# Gluing battens to chip board ceiling

Tags: ceiling, adhesive

As part of our house improvements we're having a new roof fitted. The roof is going to have an airtight layer of treated chipboard beneath the rafters which will be screwed and taped for airtightness to the rafters.

Now, it is my plan to glue 50mm battens to the chip in order to suspend a plasterboard ceiling beneath the chipboard. My builder tells me he has not used glue for that purpose, but is happy to give it a go if I tell him what to do.

I'm pretty convinced that there is some modern glue that will work just fine for this application, but it obviously wants to be quick fixing and permanent, lest I want to have someone standing and holding it for several hours. The load won't be huge (plasterboard + plaster + some lights and cable), but I want to get it right.

Is anybody able to advise on what sort of product I should be considering? Are the grab adhesives right for this? Or an alternative strategy?

Comment: 1) What's the purpose of the "chipboard", 2) why are you using battens instead of attaching the drywall to the rafters or directly to the chipboard, and 3) why do you think they should be glued in place?

Comment: The chip board is an airtight layer, tied into the walls at either side. The battens are to support the suspended ceiling so that recessed lights can be fitted and wires routed without penetrating the airtight layer. The point of gluing is to avoid piercing the airtight layer.

Comment: Screws run through sheathing do not allow air movement to any significant degree. I'd attach your battens with screws that penetrate into your rafters at least one inch (25mm). You could get construction adhesive to work, but you'd have to hold it in place somehow, and then you're at the mercy of the surface integrity of chipboard.